# Visual Studio will not launch Chrome when running Node.js

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, google-chrome, ntvs

I am using Node.js Tools for Visual Studio with VS 2015.

When I click run the app (hit the Chrome button with green arrow) my Express server starts listening. However Visual Studio doesn't automatically launch Chrome.

When I open Chrome myself, then I am able to access the Node app.

I wonder if this has something to do with how my `bin/www` is configured, but sadly I am not able to find an answer on how to fix this.

Below is `bin/www` for my app:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('ExpressApp3');
var app = require('../app');

//app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('port', 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

P.S. I always want my express server to listen on port 3000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my `bin/www` to listen on process.env.PORT

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('ExpressApp3');
var app = require('../app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

But it was causing the Express server to listen on random ports.
Then I accessed `Project Properties and added "PORT:3000"`. (I had the Node.js port set to 3000 previously but that was seemingly not making any difference).

[image: Project Properties]